# Checking balance of msg.sender before 'approve'

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I analyzed this token contract on open-zepplin here : https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol

I wonder why there is not a statement in `approve` function which should check whether owner holds those tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Because the balance is checked at `transferFrom` anyway. In between the calls, the balance could have been updated; the user could have transfered their tokens just before `transferFrom` is called. That means that any security has to be implemented on `transferFrom`, and when that is done, `approve` does not need to do the checks

Comment: I agree with the check in `transferFrom` but how this case feels, a person who doesn't own any tokens can approve another address for spending them. This doesn't look like an ideal case.

Comment: What does an approval mean if `tranferFrom` cannot be carried out? Nothing, I'd say. So, there should be no problem.